# Setting a default value for a variable in function in python

Tags: python, function

Here I have a function

```
def myfunc(some_text, argument):
    print(some_text)
    if argument == True:
        print("Argument is True")
```

But I want it make it so that if I dont type anything for argument, it should just assume it as False instead of giving me an error saying that its missing one argument.

Comment: doest work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your function signature to look like the following:

```
def myfunc(some_text, argument=False):
    print(some_text)
    if argument == True:
        print("Argument is True")
```

When you set a function parameter using '=', it assumes this value unless something different is passed in